# How to overwrite git repository with new project?

Tags: git

I have private repository with an old project and cloned it to the public one. Now I want to upload new project to this repository. How can I do this without fetching and merging stuff, but with only brute force?

Comment: `git push -f <remote> <branch>`

Comment: Do you want to retain the history of the original project? Why don't you just create a new repository for the new project?

Comment: The point is to overwrite the existing repository without deleting the history of commits. Anyway I can't do it by some reasons.

Comment: "Overwrite without deleting" makes no sense. Also, can you expand on "I can't do it by some reasons" - what are these reasons, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You would remove the directory containing the `.git` directory. Then you would `git clone <LOCATION>` and it would work.

Make sure you backup any files you want to have after the directory is deleted.

Comment: Alternatively, do `git clone` in a completely new directory to avoid losing files that might be needed in the future.

Comment: But you described the opposite process.

Comment: I don't need to overwrite my local directory with git repository, but to overwrite git repository with new local directory.

Comment: You've since edited your question, but the original question described a different problem, and my solution was to that original problem.

Comment: What? I didn't change it.